# What's the difference between declaring a protocol with/without any word?

Tags: swift

Consider these 2 declarations:

```
let a: any Protocol
```

and

```
let a: Protocol
```

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the "[existential `any`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md)".

When you use a protocol type as the type of a variable or function return type etc, that type is an existential type. Compared to concrete types (e.g. classes, structs), existential types have more limitations and also performance implications. Here is an example from the Swift Evolution proposal, illustrating the difference.

```
protocol P {
  associatedtype A
  func test(a: A)
}

func generic<ConcreteP: P>(p: ConcreteP, value: ConcreteP.A) {
  p.test(a: value)
}

func useExistential(p: P) {
  generic(p: p, value: ???) // what type of value would P.A be??
}
```

Before `any` was introduced, you write existential types and concrete types the same way - by just writing their names. This makes it not very clear what is an existential type and what isn't. Since existential types behave very differently, it is useful to explicitly tell the reader that "this is an existential type". This is what `any` is for.

See also the [Motivation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md#motivation) section.

From Swift 6 and onwards, all existential types must be written with the `any` prefix.

In Swift 5, you are still allowed to write protocol types that has no associated type/`Self` requirements, without the `any`. See also the [Source Compatibility](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md#source-compatibility) section.

> To minimize the amount of new code written that will become invalid in Swift 6, I propose requiring any immediately for protocols with Self and associated type requirements.

This is why `P` and `any P` are both valid. They mean the same thing - the existential type `any P`. In Swift 6, though, writing `P` here would not be valid.

Comment: So just to be clear: both `P` and `any P` have the same performance, right? It's just that Swift 5.x allows you to skip that `any` in some cases.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis correct.